# Run a function at a random time in Python

Tags: python, function, random, time

I want to be able to be able to run a function at a random time as long as the program is running.

Let's say I have this function:

```
def sample_func:
    print("Function is running.")
```

and some other code running. As long as the program is being run, I want this function to run at a random amount of time between 5 to 10 minutes while other code is being run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you're looking. Set the sleep timer for 5-10 minutes.
Insert your main flow code inside the "main flow" function.

```py
import random
import threading
import time


def random_function():
    print("Function is running.")


def call_random_function():
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        random_function()


def main_flow():
    """
    Do your main flow here
    """
    a = 1
    while a < 10:
        print(a)
        a += 1
        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=call_random_function).start()
    main_flow()
    print("Program is finished.")
```